# Android intent did not return correct map location

Tags: android, android-intent, uri

I've coded an intent for an street address lookup in my Android application.

### When the map button is pressed, Google Maps opens, but it is displaying the current location of the cell phone, rather than the Uri coded street address.

```
public void onClickOpenAddressButton(View v) {
    //Store an address in a String
    String addressString = "1600 Pennsylvania Ave NW, Washington, DC 20500";

    // Used Uri.Builder to form the Uri for the address
    Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
    builder.scheme("geo")
            .path("0,0")
            .query(addressString);
    Uri addressUri = builder.build();

    // A call to showMap, passing in the Uri from the previous step
    showMap(addressUri);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

because you using string address
Try Using lat & long
For sending request to Google map you should send latitude and longitude, it's the only way to point in correct location.

Comment: I'm trying to use street address for the search, and in the specs, I read that you set lat and long to 0 if you are using a street address in your intent.

Comment: If you use street address, it will not point correctly cause, you should change the code and use lat and long instead